# Homeomorphism for Alexandroff extension

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I can't find any tool I can use.

Show that the following spaces are homeomorphic:

$$
Q = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : |x|+|y| \le 1\}\quad \text {and} \quad  \alpha X$$ where $\alpha X$ is the  Alexandroff compactification of $X=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2:  |x|+|y| \le 1, x+y<1\}$ .

Comment: $X$ and $Q$ are not homeomorphic. Do you mean that $Q$ is homeomorphic to the 1-point (Alexandroff) compactification $\alpha X$ of $X$?

Comment: I meant homeomorphic to the Alexandroff compactification. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Use \le and \ge for $\le$ and $\ge$. I replaced "$|$" with "$:$" to make reading easier (because of the absolute-value symbols). And corrected \Bbb R to \Bbb R^2. (... \Bbb is the same as \mathbb ).

Comment: Use rubber-sheet geometry (Silly Putty geometry) to squeeze $X$ in a way that squeezes the "edge" $\{(x,y): |x|+|y|\le 1\land x+y=1\}$ (which is not part of $X$) to a single point

Comment: Let A=(-1,0), B=(0,1),C=(1,0),D=(0,-1). Let E be the mid-point of AB. For any P on AD with P$\ne$ A, take P' on BC with PP' parallel to AB.  Let PP' meet DE at Q and let PP' meet  CE at Q'. Now map PP' linearly to QQ' with P going to Q and with P' going to Q'. This maps X to the triangle BCE plus its interior but minus the point E.

Comment: I got the picture wrong in my last comment but I think you should understand the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.